# How do you catch an error in this timer code for discord.js?

Tags: javascript, timer, discord.js, bots

I'm making a discord bot in javascript, and I'm trying to make it so when someone inputs a time that isn't valid, that it tells you that you have an error, instead of crashing the bot.

I've been working on it for a while and cannot find an answer to how to stop it from crashing the bot and just replying with something like, "That is not a valid number." Could someone help me?

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'timer':
      let time = (args[1]);
      if (!time) {
        return message.reply("You didnt specify a time!");
      }
      message.reply(`Timer started for ${ms(ms(time))}`)
      setTimeout(function() {
        message.reply(`your timer has stopped`)
      }, ms(time));
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
if(isNaN(time)) return message.reply("That is not a valid number.")
```

`isNaN()` returns `true` for "Not a Number" values, which should be exactly what you need, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Answer (score 1):

#### isNaN()

isNaN is a JavaScript function that returns a boolean to determine whether a given input is a number or not. It stands for **is Not a Number**.
A few examples:

```
isNaN(8); // Expected outcome 'false' since 8 is a number
isNaN('hello!'); // Expected outcome 'true' since 'hello!' is not a number.
// It also works for numbers inside of a string:
isNaN('23'); // Expected outcome 'false' since 23 is a number.
```

You can read more about isNaN() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

#### In your code

From this logic, we're able to use this for your code by checking whether or not the second argument was a number or not => in this case, the variable 'time':

```
if (isNaN(time)) return message.reply('Please enter a number!');
```